# The orbit space GL(n,R)/O(n)

Tags: fiber-bundles, orthogonal-matrices, linear-groups, general-linear-group

If $G= GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $H= O(n)$ then why the orbit space
$G/H$ is homeomorphic to the space of all upper triangular
matrices with positive diagonal entries?(Here action of $H$ on $G$ is the usual matrix multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition): every $M\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ can be written in one and only one way as $TQ$, where $T$ is upper triangular and $Q$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand